# How do I get a Hotmail contact list in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, hotmail

How can I get a Hotmail contact list in C#? Are there any working examples? I haven't found any either through Google or through a Stack Overflow search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the website for the [Windows Live Contacts API](http://dev.live.com/contacts/); it should give you what you're looking for, although I haven't used it myself. Looks like you need to download the Windows Live SDK from the Downloads tab on that site.

I found it via [this MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wliddev/thread/cbb531ae-ed85-4e4f-8565-8bddbfa1c232) which talks about a possible future Hotmail API, but as far as I can tell, a full Hotmail API doesn't exist (yet).

Comment: Windows live contacts api (http://dev.live.com/contacts/) is a good start point. Now i can get contact list.

Answer (score 1):

With live connect you can only get hash of the contact emails, but not actual mails, do not loose time on that

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243648.aspx#contact

"An array containing a SHA-256 hash for each of the contact's email addresses."

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse-engineer the DeltaSync protocol. I think i got that far, will  add link later.

Answer (score 0):

As Брайков said, Microsoft no longer allow developer to get the contact emails from their Live Connect Service API

Microsoft still allows some company to use their old API like:
http://www.cloudsponge.com/ (i am not work for this kind of company, but i really cannot find a updated open source api to grep hotmail/live contacts list with real email address)